Home server setup
I've a desktop PC that I no longer use that I'm going to turn into a home server. I'll use it as a DC and FS server, but I need to know some things if anybody could help. Would my laptop, that will be connected by domain, require me to be on this network to log on? I know some could say ' We cant sign you in with this credential because the domain could not be found'. If so, how do I stop this? Thanks

when I worked enterprise, there was generally caching going on and we generally didn't need to get into the corporate network to log in.

The line "...I need to know some things if anybody could help" sounds as though you are asking for general advice in addition to your specific question. This site requires single questions in each post. Please consider editing your post to remove or clarify this line.


Would my laptop, that will be connected by domain, require me to be on this network to log on?

Usually not, as Windows stores cached credentials for the last X users that have logged in (that is, a PBKDF2 hash of the last successful password is stashed in your Registry) – given that your laptop is probably going to be used by 1 account total, it should always retain cached credentials for you.
(If I remember correctly, it will also keep your password in memory so that it'll be able to automatically get Kerberos tickets later... although that already happens when unlocking the laptop anyway.)
The "We cant sign you in with this credential because the domain could not be found" error message only shows up when you try to sign in with an account whose credentials Windows does not have cached. (Or, of course, if the domain administrator has disabled credential caching via GPO.)
You can also avoid this by setting up an "always-on VPN" tunnel through which your system could talk to the DCs. (Active Directory uses TCP/IP, you don't need to be "on the same subnet" or anything.)

nice to know. So that message/being locked out only occurs if a company sets a GPO to enforce network only log on? It's just cuz in my last corp job I couldn't log in at home before doing a lockscreen vpn. Thanks!

Well, there might be other reasons but I believe this is the most common cause. (As far as I know, it's common for admins to disable credential caching, both because it's another thing that could be stolen and possibly cracked, and because it ignores account lockout – even if your account is disabled and you no longer have file server access, it still allows you to log in to your workstation or laptop just by disconnecting it from the network.)
